# MySql.Data dll not working for others in C# Program

Tags: c#

So I have added MySql.Data dll as a reference in my project.

But it doesn't work on others' computers.

I did set "Copy Local" to "true".

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone tell me what I need to add to my code?

The error is:

> SkypeBot has stopped working

And when I remove

> using MySql;

and

> using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

It works fine.

Comment: what error do you get on other computers when you try to run the program?

Comment: Just edited it, its now there

Comment: Does the DLL actually exist in the application directory on the user's machine?  "Copy Local" means to the build directory, not to the user's machine.

Comment: Then what should I do? i did a NuGet thing and added MySql.Data and removed MYSql.Data as a reference, still no results. Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having to do all this, I just wrote a PHP code which is called in the application when needed, which stores it all in the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the possible cause could be that your computer is **installed with MySQL installer** other computer didn't. What you can do is

**1) install the MySQL installer on other computer as well**

**2) install the nugget package for the project and then use on other computers as well**

Comment: The program is being used by 15+ people.

I don't want to have to install it on every PC.

Is there no easier way??

Comment: Then install the nugget package. I was having the same problem on my computer as well. So this nugget package installation process worked'

Comment: Can you give me more detail into this? I've never done it before

Comment: Just don't add the DLL reference directly to your project but install the nugget for it. Please post the exact error on other machine you're facing for enabling me to figure it out.

Comment: The error on other computers: "Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=randomcharacters' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.". I added the NuGet package by right clicking my solution and clicking "Manage NuGet Packages..." and installing MySql.data

Comment: Now this is the problem with Your web.config file. Kindly edit Your question and add the MySql registering section of the web.config file. Let me review it. And if MySql nugget package version is not mentioned earlier then do mention that as well.